# How to hardcopy to multiple pages per sheet?

Tags: vim

Let's suppose I have a single sheet of `text` to print (8.5''x11'').  Can I create multiple hardcopies of said text and scale them so that I can fit 4 copies per print sheet using VIM?

ex.

```
___________         ___________ 
text                text  text
              ->    

              ->    text  text

___________         ___________
```

Comment: Why in vim? If you print using `a2ps -4 ` you should get 4 up.

Comment: Yes you're right that it doesn't have to be VIM.  I was interested using a command within the editor since I am used to using the hardcopy command.

Comment: Is this always going to be one page? Or could it be any number of pages?

Comment: Always one page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be the easiest way but you could

1. save the text to `in.txt` and render your text to PostScript e.g:

   ```
   a2ps -1 in.txt -o 1.ps
   ```

   make sure your 1.ps looks like you want it to, `a2ps` normally adds a border and header. Any PostScript output will do (or PDF, with which you can skip the next step).
2. convert the PostScript to PDF:

   ```
   ps2pdf 1.ps
   ```
3. create a pdf file with four times this page:

   ```
   pdftk 1.pdf 1.pdf 1.pdf 1.pdf cat output 4.pdf
   ```
4. back to PostScript:

   ```
   pdf2ps 4.pdf
   ```
5. 4-up the output to make one page from four:

   ```
   psnup -4 4.ps > out.ps
   ```
6. Print final product

   ```
   lpr out.ps
   ```

Comment: This worked with a few edits.  I wrapped everything in a bash script which takes 3 arguments: the filename, number of 'texts' per sheet, and number of copies to be printed.  It also 'rm'  the temporary files.  Do you think it would be useful to post it?

Comment: Why produce postscript, convert it to PDF, and go back to PS? You could stay in PS or PDF for the whole chain.

Comment: @Gilles I am used to a tools that handle PostScript and PDF the same way as well. But when I tried Step 3  with `1.ps` as input, and step 5. with 4.pdf as input, they did not give the result I expected. This way they do, although in an inelegant way.

Comment: And I did not know of a tool for PostScript that does the assembling that I know `pdftk` could do, which is not to say there isn't one, and that could save the two conversion steps.